# React: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting this problem `TypeError: undefined is not a function` and I did not recognize the error,
this is my code.
I have included the full code of this component in order to be clear

```
import React, {Component, useState,useEffect} from "react";

function Counter() {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const[materiel,setMateriels]=useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/materiels")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setMateriels(data);
                console.log(materiels);
            })
            .catch(console.log);
    }, []);
}


class searchMateriel extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="container">
                <div className="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={event => {
                        this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value});
                    }}/>
                    {this.state.materiels
                        .filter((val) => val.nom.startsWith(this.statesearchTerm))
                        .map((val, key) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="user" key={{key}}>
                                    <p>{val.nom}</p>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    state = {
        materiels: [],
        searchTerm: "",
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/materiels')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({materiels: data})
                console.log(this.state.materiels)
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }
}

export default searchMateriel;
```

I have updated the code but still not working.
It is showing this error

```
Line 11:29:  'materiels' is not defined
```

The error is in the last line of my code, does anyone please have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe `setSearchTerm` isn't available to `Counter`, therefore `undefined` is found, thus is not a function.

Comment: I have edited with the full code . I did not understand your requesr

Comment: why you are keeping the counter as a different hook?

Comment: That's not the way to implement hooks, I suggest you head over the official docs to understand how to write a functional component. Also, consider stop using class components which is why hooks have been created - instead of componentDidMount, use useEffect instead

Answer (score 0):

Your code/use-case is wrong, in this code `Counter` is a functional component, so React except that to return some JSX's...
you get undefined because `Counter` returns nothing then you want to access the `setSearchTerm` method... basically, you will get the `undefined is not a function react js` error.

to store the input value in the state, you can pass the parent setState to the children or define a state in it.

NOTE: if you merely want to store your state in another place and process it, you can use hooks.

Comment: thanks I have modified the code but still not working, check my post

Answer (score 0):

Counter in the code above is just a function, which actually doesn't return anything. Also Counter doesn't have setSearchTerm method which you are trying to access. You cannot use a hook outside of the top level of a functional component or hook [see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)
As you are using class-based components, you should use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) method to update your state or switch to functional component and use [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
I don't see any usage of searchTerm in your code, but I am assuming, that you will add a function to your filter function.

```
class searchMateriel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="col-xs-12">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChange={(event) => {
              this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value });
            }}
          />
          {this.state.materiels
            .filter((val) => val.nom.startsWith(this.statesearchTerm))
            .map((val, key) => {
              return (
                <div className="user" key={{ key }}>
                  <p>{val.nom}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  state = {
    materiels: [],
    searchTerm: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/materiels")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ materiels: data });
        console.log(this.state.materiels);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
}

export default searchMateriel;
```

Also, I wanted to mention that in class-based components state is merged when you are using setState but when you are using useState hook state is completely replaced

If you would like to replace your class-based component with functional one, it could look like this:

```
const searchMateriel = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [materiels, setMateriels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/materiels")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setMateriels(data);
        console.log(materiels);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={(event) => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        {materiels
          .filter((val) => val.nom.startsWith(searchTerm))
          .map((val, key) => {
            return (
              <div className="user" key={{ key }}>
                <p>{val.nom}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default searchMateriel;
```

More about useEffect you can read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but it still not working , can you check my post please?

Comment: You cannot use useState inside of Counter function as it is not a functional component. You are trying to console.log(materiels); but you have defined materiel. Also I don't see usage of this Counter

Answer (score 0):

seeing you are not defining `state` in **constructor**. this may be the reason. Constructor loads before component is mounted. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor